# How to join windows client to ubuntu OpenLDAP domain server

Tags: 12.04, networking, domain-server, openldap

I've configured an OpenLDAP server on my Ubuntu 12.04 server. I also configured a DNS server for domain support. My slapd service is running perfectly and I can see it with my LDAP browser. Using *phpldapadmin* I am able to create OU and users.

But I don't know how to connect a windows client to my Ubuntu OpenLDAP domain.
I want to make this Ubuntu OpenLDAP domain server to be the centralized server for all windows client.

Can you help me connecting windows clients to my OpenLDAP server?

Answer (score 0):

Historically, Windows and OpenLDAP don't play along nicely. Your best bet may be to use the [pGina](http://pgina.org/) Windows application to add LDAP authentication to the Windows client in question, over attempting to force Windows to authenticate with OpenLDAP as a default behavior.